# EF Core with '&&' and '||' inside lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

The following query is not returning the proper results, it will return properly for company, but not the other two parameters. For clarification this is inside a post method of a page taking the user's input for company, name, and/or state

```
var transporters = await _db.TransporterProfiles
                            .Include(x => x.TransportState)
                            .Where(x => x.Company == company || company == null &&
                                   x => x.LastName == name || name == null &&
                                   x => x.TransportState.Name == state || state == null)
                            .ToListAsync();
```

I've tried adding parentheses around each part of the query such as

```
.Where((x => x.Company == company || company == null) &&
       (x => x.LastName == name || name == null) &&
       (x => x.TransportState.Name == state || state == null))
```

but this produces an error

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression'

Comment: What you posted is an attempt to recreate a "catch-all" SQL query in LINQ. Such queries cause performance problems and aren't needed when you can create the query dynamically on the client

Comment: What you mean by ```company == null``` ?

Comment: company, name and state are all user input values

Comment: So you want to get rows where ```Company == company``` or ```Company   == null``` ?

Comment: I want to get rows where x.Company(from DB) == company(user input) UNLESS company(user input) == null. That goes for all three values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to include `company == null` in the query. If you don't want a search term, don't include it at all. You can build AND conditions by adding `Where` clauses to a query as needed, eg :

```
if(value1 != null)
{
    query=query.Where(x=>x.Property1 == value1);
}
if(value2 != null)
{
    query=query.Where(x=>x.Property2 == value2);
}
```

In the question's case you can write something like this:

```
var query=_db.TransporterProfiles.Include(x => x.TransportState).AsQueryable();
if(company!=null)
{
    query=query.Where(x => x.Company == company);
}
if(name!=null)
{
    query=query.Where(x => x.LastName == name);
}
if(state!=null)
{
    query=query.Where(x => x.TransportState.Name == state);
}

var transporters=await query.ToListAsync();
```

You don't need to include `TransportState` to use `x.TransportState.Name` in the `Where` clause. `Include` is used to eagerly load related data, not tell EF to JOIN between related tables.

If you don't want `Include` you can start the query with :

```
var query=_db.TransporterProfiles.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: this produces the following error:

CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Adding the explicit cast allowed it to build, but then when going to the page returned an error. I tried using AsQueryable() and that produces no errors during compile or runtime, but returned zero results

Comment: What `type1` to `type2` ? Where? What did you actually try?

Comment: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TP.Core.Domain.TransporterProfile>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludable<TP.Core.Domain.TransporterProfile, TP.Core.Domain.Directory.TransportState>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 

Which I then attempted the potential fix inside Visual Studio of adding the explicit cast

Comment: @ShawnVinje - instead of `var transporters =` write it explicitly as `IQueryable<TransporterProfile> transporters = `

Comment: If this is EF core, this form `(x.Company == company || company == null)` can be used. EF core is smart enough to translate this in `x.Company == company` only if `company` isn't nul, or else ignore the predicate entirely, thus doing automatically what you do here. But then, unfortunately we don't know OP's EF version.

Comment: @ShawnVinje add `AsQueryable()` at the end then. It's the same reason you have to use `AsQueryable` with DbSet - the classes implement IQueryable explicitly, which means you have to explicitly cast them to IQueryable to use LINQ

Comment: @GertArnold it's better to avoid bad idioms than depend on a tool to fix the code. EF Core 6+ can fix quite a lot of bad idioms but what happens when that fails? Or people assume it works better than it does? `FromSqlInterpolated` tried to fix SQL injection but then we got a ton of questions when people tried to extract the pattern into an interpolated string. Myself included - even after answering a dozen such questions.

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your syntax is you have multiple lambdas that should be one.

```
.Where(x => (x.Company == company || company == null) &&
   (x.LastName == name || name == null) &&
   (x.TransportState.Name == state || state == null))
```

That said the actual solution is to do what @PanagiotisKanavos posted as an answer, generate the query dynamically based on the input values.

Comment: As Gert Arnold commented, EF Core detects this pattern and eliminates the dead clauses. Which is cool ... but I'd rather not depend on this. This question is a case where a tiny mistake will lead to problems

Comment: I learned something new, thanks for your follow up comment @PanagiotisKanavos.